# How to group styles,npm packages or your own ideas？

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm

```css
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Is there such an `npm` package that can convert the above `css` code into the following code?

```css
.a,.b {
    width: 100px;
}
.a {
    height:50px;
}
```

just make the `css` code smaller as much as possible, say your thoughts or recommend a `npm` package.

Comment: Search keywords that should help you find a few options: “CSS minifier”.

Comment: Just minify your css. There are many ways to do so (i think also npm packages or you could even paste your css online and minify it there). Minifying will not do what you described above but it will remove all spaces (which will save more than enough bytes)

Comment: @TimGerhard: Some minifiers can actually do what’s described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I wanted：

Npm package called `clean-css`

this package can achieve the results I want.

E.g:

```js
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height:50px;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Will be compressed into：

```js
.a,.b{width:100px}.a{height:50px}
```

You can search for the website `refresh-sf`, group and compress css online.